# How to resolve conflict dependencies ubuntu apache2.4?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I can not install Apache2.4. Requires dependency. Result:

[apt-get install apache2](http://joxi.ru/F22ZU_3JTJAoYzyNWbU)

[apt-get install apache2-bin](http://joxi.ru/PW2ZUxjKTJBaH-5FREI)

Comment: which version of Ubuntu ere you running?

Comment: choose a different download server.

Comment: for example? Can you offer?

Comment: I changed repo. Result: http://joxi.ru/Q46ZUxjKTJBOH9Fw0KE

Comment: did you update the repositories by running `sudo apt-get update` after changing the downloading server?

Comment: Yes of course. Changes only the list of dependencies